How to get the user local system date and time and store the data in tinestamp format in Database
How to get the user local system date and time and store the data in tinestamp format in Database in js
I tried new Date() function but I got GMT time format if the local system is in India I need to get indian datetime if the local system is in us I need to get us date time

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Date's .toLocaleString() method "returns a string with a language-sensitive representation of the date portion of this date in the local timezone"


console.log( new Date().toLocaleString() )



